# Bootstrap doesn't seem to be importing

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to RoR and have been following along with Michael Hartl's tutorial and have now been stuck on the part that introduces the Bootstrap framework. All gems are being updated and installed.

locales/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
     config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) 
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "default", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>

<div class="center hero-unit">
<h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

<h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
</h2>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "bttn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

html    {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

border-style: {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
    overflow:auto;
}

textarea    {
    resize: vertical;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.center h1  {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Something that I've gathered is most likely incorrect is the fact that the source code of /home.html.erb does not make any references to /styles/bootscrap.css . Should I have a bootstrap.css file along with my other stylesheets? If so it's not mentioned in the tut.

```
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/stylesheets/default.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/javascripts/default.js"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="n2QVul+/didf2xA6jj3QelpDZdOrUpgaWcDp1XFQACM=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<! [endif]
```

This is what /static_pages/home looks like for me :
[my home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ngqc.png)

vs. the one from the tutorial : [tutorial home](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/images/figures/sample_app_logo_4_0.png)
I can't think of anything else to include but if I've missed something I'll be sure to follow up quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application.html.erb,
it should be "application", not "default".

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: Thank you. I had been reading tons and tons of different questions/answers here on stackoverflow and that was one of the suggestions that I thought I'd try. After a few minutes of referring to the tutorial github and following the error trail I think I have things working. Sometimes it takes another set of eyes.